# indexPathsForSelectedItems not return IndexPath on Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I am using Swift 3 to get `indexPath` for selected items. The code looks like this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
    print(indexPaths) 
}
```

But this one print out empty array such as `[]` rather than an array of selected items of collection view cell. How can I get the `indexPath` row of selected cell?

Comment: did you unselect the item in the selected delegate function?

Comment: You need to show your `didSelectItemAt indexPath` method.

Comment: i have selected delegate function. But it still return zero array.

Comment: @fzlrhmn Add the code of `didSelectItemAt indexPath` in your question.

Comment: I know what is wrong with my code. I have used `didDeselectItemAt` rather than `didSelectItemAt`. Case closed. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I know what is wrong with my code. I have used `didDeselectItemAt` rather than `didSelectItemAt`. Case closed. Thanks all.